# Android BLE Advertisement gives error codes 1, 10 and 14 and status as 18

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

I am making an app for BLE advertisement but as soon as I press the start transmitting button I get the toast message `status` as 18 and when I check the logcat I see error codes `1, 10 and 14`.

I have included all permissions in the `manifest.xml` file also.

Here is the advertisement code:

```
public void onAdvertiseButtonPressed(View view){
        final Button advertiseButton=(Button)view;

        Log.i(TAG,"Advertise mode:"+advertiseMode);
        Log.i(TAG,"Advertise power:"+advertisePower);


        AdvertiseData advertiseData = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
                .build();
        BluetoothLeAdvertiser bluetoothLeAdvertiser=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();



            AdvertisingSetParameters parameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
                    .setInterval(advertiseInterval)
                    .setTxPowerLevel(advertisePower)
                    .setScannable(true)
                    .setConnectable(false)
                    .build();


            AdvertisingSetCallback advertisingSetCallback = new AdvertisingSetCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onAdvertisingSetStarted(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet, int txPower, int status) {
                    super.onAdvertisingSetStarted(advertisingSet, txPower, status);
                    Log.i(TAG,"Advertising set started:::" + advertisingSet + ",txPower:"+txPower+",status:"+status);
                    if(advertisingSet!=null) {
                        advertisingSet.enableAdvertising(true, 0, 0);
                        advertiseButton.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(TransmitActivity.this, "Start adv error status:"+status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdvertisingSetStopped(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet) {
                    super.onAdvertisingSetStopped(advertisingSet);
                    Log.i(TAG,"Advertising set stopped");
                    activeAdvertiseCallback = null;
                    handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                        advertiseButton.setEnabled(true);
                        if(!isStopped)
                            onAdvertiseButtonPressed(advertiseButton);
                    }, 1);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAdvertisingEnabled(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet, boolean enable, int status) {
                    super.onAdvertisingEnabled(advertisingSet, enable, status);
                    Log.i(TAG,"Advertising set enabled:"+enable + "status:" + status);
                    if(enable){
                        activeAdvertiseCallback = this;
                        handler.postDelayed(()-> {
                            bluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertisingSet(this);
                        },1);
                    }
                }
            };
            if (bluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Advertiser not found, isBluetoothOn " + BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isEnabled());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Advertiser not found, isBluetoothOn " + BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isEnabled(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                time = System.currentTimeMillis ();
                bluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertisingSet(parameters, advertiseData, null, null, null, advertisingSetCallback);


            }

    }
```

Logcat:

```
2020-06-28 23:16:09.471 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/CheckPermission: _bluetooth code = 1 
2020-06-28 23:16:10.736 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/ColorViewRootUtil: nav gesture mode swipeFromBottom ignore false downY 951 mScreenHeight 2340 mScreenWidth 1080 mStatusBarHeight 54 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 3 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=114.0, y[0]=951.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=330086863, downTime=330086863, deviceId=6, source=0x1002, displayId=0 } rotation 0
2020-06-28 23:16:14.980 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/ColorViewRootUtil: nav gesture mode swipeFromBottom ignore false downY 1389 mScreenHeight 2340 mScreenWidth 1080 mStatusBarHeight 54 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 3 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=763.0, y[0]=1389.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=330091106, downTime=330091106, deviceId=6, source=0x1002, displayId=0 } rotation 0
2020-06-28 23:16:15.097 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/CheckPermission: _bluetooth code = 14 
2020-06-28 23:16:15.099 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/CheckPermission: _bluetooth code = 14 
2020-06-28 23:16:15.102 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/CheckPermission: _bluetooth code = 10 
2020-06-28 23:18:06.785 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/ColorViewRootUtil: nav gesture mode swipeFromBottom ignore false downY 1414 mScreenHeight 2340 mScreenWidth 1080 mStatusBarHeight 54 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 3 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=837.0, y[0]=1414.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=330202905, downTime=330202905, deviceId=6, source=0x1002, displayId=0 } rotation 0
2020-06-28 23:18:06.872 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/CheckPermission: _bluetooth code = 14 
2020-06-28 23:18:06.874 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/CheckPermission: _bluetooth code = 14 
2020-06-28 23:18:06.878 11505-11505/com.example.bleexperiments E/CheckPermission: _bluetooth code = 10
```

Comment: Hi, i'm getting E/CheckPermission: _bluetooth code = 10 have you solved this issue ? thx

Comment: Getting 18 as an error status-code and for the life of me I can't figure out what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as you, my solution is, instead of using startAdvertisingSet, use startAdvertising. The only downside of this is that the broadcast interval cannot be set. If there is no special requirement, I think it is a good choice to use startAdvertising instead.